# I can't add ApplicationRoleManager to startup.auth

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

The question is pretty simple, I'm trying to implement roles into my application, and most if not all places that I go to, tell me to use the following line in the startup.auth:

```
 app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
```

The problem is, Visual studio keeps telling me that ApplicationRoleManager doesn't exist! I already searched for different ways to maybe implement this, but everyone keeps saying "use ApplicationRoleManager", but I can't use it and apparently, I already got the libraries needed for it too.

Any help is very welcome here.

Apparently, my application didn't auto-generate the ApplicationRoleManager code, so i'm trying to add it manually. In IdentityConfig.Cs I have added the following code:

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore)
    {
    }
}
```

At this point i'm stuck, because apparently I need other methods (like the create method) to make this work, but I cannot find any example of this code to add.

**EDIT** I am currently trying to implement a factory to implement the role management. But I'm having problems with VS not detecting certain objects, here's a picture to show it off better:

[image: Capture]

I have updated my identity packages in nuget, I'm still having problems with the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a factory to create the role manager. So the create method is the only method you should implement. But to be honest you don't need either if you don't want. So there are two ways of doing this:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>(new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole, string>(new SomeContext()));
```

Or you can create a factory to do it for you:

```
public class RoleManagerFactory
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<SomeContext> contextFactory
    public RoleManagerFactory(IDbContextFactory<SomeContext> contextFactory)
    {
         this.contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    public RoleManager<IdentityRole> Create()
    {
        return new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole, string>(contextFactory.Create()));
    }

    // If you have already instantiated a context to use, then you can pass it in here
    public RoleManager<IdentityRole> Create(SomeContext context)
    {
        return new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole, string>(context));
    }
}

var factory = new RoleManagerFactory();
app.CreatePerOwinContext<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>(factory.Create());
```

I believe these ways are easier than what you are trying to do.

***EDIT***

I added the context factory in, because I remembered you need to pass a context into the role store. So EntityFramework already as a `IDbContextFactory<TContext>` interface, so you just need to create a concrete implementation and implement the interface, which is another `Create` method where you return a new context: `new SomeContext()`.

This is what I do in my apps. In fact I use dependency injection and make the role manager be created per request. I use this factory so that I can inject the role manager into my classes:

```
public interface IRoleManagerFactory
{
    RoleManager<IdentityRole> Create();
}
```

So in  my classes I can do this:

```
public class RoleController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRoleManagerFactory roleManagerFactory;

    public RoleController (IRoleManagerFactory roleManagerFactory)
    {
         this.roleManagerFactory = roleManagerFactory;
    }

    // Create method
    public async Task<JsonResult> CreateRole(string role)
    {
        using (var roleManager = this.roleManagerFactory.Create())
        {
            var result = await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);

            return Json(new { succeeded: result.Succeeded });
        }
    }
}
```

***EDIT***

I have updated the example with correct usage of role manager and db context.

Comment: That seems to be the best answer, unfortunately I seem to be having another problem now. Visual studio can't find RoleStore and it doesn't let me use resolve to get the libray. Any ideas?

Comment: Nuget the Identity stuff, let me find you a link

Comment: Here is the identity stuff from nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/2.1.0

Comment: Visual studio still doesn't detect it even after updating using nuget, added details to original post.

Comment: Are you doing an Api project or a MVC project?

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect the fact you maybe using MVC. Also I remembered that the role store needs a context, so I have included the code for that.